# Issue in Visual Studio 2012 release build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have a program which runs fine in debug build , but when I run the same with release build my program crashes at below lines

```
char* iter=ptr; //ptr is already initialized

char* iter = (char*) ALIGN (iter); // crashes here
```

I have a preprocessor  definition like below for ALIGN

Type-casting of pointers to long.

```
#define SIZE       8L
#define ALIGN(ptr)  \
    (((__int64)ptr & (~(SIZE - 1L))) + SIZE) \

       : (__int64)ptr)
```

It only gives problem when I run this program in Visual Studio 2012 in windows 8 but works fine with Visual studio 2012 in windows 7 .
I dont know what flags(may be optimization flags) we have to set or unset for my program  to work in release mode.
Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing is, basically

```
char* iter = iter;
```

If the variable `iter` is declared as a local variable, its contents will be indeterminate, and using that value will lead to undefined behavior. That includes using that value to initialize itself.

Comment: Hey my apologies , Actually I for got to add one line . And When it crashes it gives an error like "Access violation writing location". Actually this program is working fine in vc9 and vc10 release modes but I don't know why it is failing in vc11 release mode in windows 8.

Comment: @user3021329 Because undefined behavior.